# Branches mixed up while trying pull request

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, branch, commit, pull

I forked my team's repo, saved changes, committed, pushed it to forked repo.

After my mixed up attempts, my tree is going crazy.

[image: Screenshot of sourcetree]

**Issues/questions**
I covered my name with blue which I will call as 'a'branch

1. Pink floating branch is my team repo. After I forked and formed remote, that branch is formed. After my attempts of revert, reset, and even deleting team repo remote, my main (default) branch is suddenly turned into team repo branch.
   => Is this common to happen when I fork and try to commit to the forked repo? How can I connect the main branch and make commit/push to the team repo?
2. My remote branches are separated everywhere origin/a, a, main, origin/main. How can I locate it in a same index?
   => I tried multiple revert, reset but it is getting worse. I am also curious if people normally use several branches and match it into same index whenever they commit on any of the branches?

How can I fix this floating branch and scattered remote branches?

Comment: a forked repository is a separate repository. It is not part of the original repository. Did you mean to clone the team repository and make commits and pushes? Or did you really want to have a fork (your own completely (well, sort of) separate repository)?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was trying to make commit/push to my team repo, so I forked team repo! I fixed the separated branch issue but now facing another issue. 

Forked team project repo is called 'pjt' (I am invited in original team repo)
My new branch for the commit/push to forked repo is 'nb'
I committed on the 'nb' branch, then pushed using command
git push -u pjt nb
But this doesn't create pull request telling error 
(forked repo owner name):main and (my ID):nb are entirely different commit histories.
It would be very helpful if you have any idea on this incident! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should rebase your branch on top of `origin/main`

```
git rebase --onto origin/main fistSHA1~ yourBranch
git push -f
```

That would be enough to restore your history on top of the remote history.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I used it to fix my separated branches